# Error 3704 Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Tags: asp-classic

I'm always getting error 3704. Operation is not allowed when object is closed.

```
Dim myConnection2, RSTitleList2        

Set myConnection2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RSTitleList2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 

myConnection2.Open "<%=connectionString%>"
sSQL1 = "Update FileInformation SET Status = 4 Where DataDefinitionID = 147 AND CustomerID = 71"
RSTitleList2.open sSQL1, myConnection2


if RSTitleList2.BOF and RSTitleList2.EOF then
    msgbox("INSERT SUCCESSFUL")
    frmProcess.cmdPublish.disabled = true

Else
    msgbox("Not SUCCESSFUL")
    msgbox(err.Number & " | " & err.description & " | " & err.Source)
End IF  

msgbox(err.Number & " | " & err.description & " | " & err.Source)
```

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` you have somewhere, it's BAD and very risky for those who don't know how to use it properly. Without it, you will now get helpful error on the line where you try to open the connection.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you gave us the line where the line number which comes with the error message.  However I can see one rather strange thing in your code

```
myConnection2.Open "<%=connectionString%>"
```

Why is "connectionstring" inside <%= %>.  That syntax is used when you want display an asp variable within your html, eg

```
<h1>Welcome, <%= username %></h1>
```

When you're already in a block of asp code, just try

```
myConnection2.Open connectionString
```